# Finding the closest option

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class Pump

```
public class Pump
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PSI_min { get; set; }
    public int PSI_max { get; set; }
    public int Horsepower_min { get; set; }
    public Bitmap Graph { get; set; }
    public int RPM { get; set; }

    public Pump (string name, int psi_min, int psi_max, int horsepower_min)
    {
        Name = name;
        PSI_min = psi_min;
        PSI_max = psi_max;
        Horsepower_min = horsepower_min;
    }
}
```

and I have a function to find a pump that fits based on user input (PSI, HP, and RPM)

```
public void Calculate()
{
        for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            Pump pump = pumps[i];

            if (pump.PSI_min <= givenPSI && pump.PSI_max >= givenPSI && pump.Horsepower_min <= givenHorsepower && pump.RPM == givenRPM)
            {
                pumpsThatFit.Add(pump);
            }
        }
```

Now, I'm trying to find a way for the program to get the closest available pump, if there are no pumps that match exactly (PSI too high HP too low, etc.). But I can't think of a way to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: You define a suitable way to weigh the importance of differing from the values wanted and find the one that has the lowest weighted difference.

Comment: Surely you have a spec for determining the "closest" pump.  Then the use math/statistics.  Closest is all in how you define it and completely arbitrary.

Comment: More specifically - define a weighted "score" based on the importance of each field, and compute the "score" for each pump.

Comment: You're going to have to weight your factors, and score them, as well as keep in mind things like two pumps matching in score, but differing in multiple fields. ("Should we ever show a pump with PSI lower than specified?") *Closest* may be the wrong term, you may want *most appropriate.* You have to define a ruleset for the selection, however.

Comment: Realistically, Horsepower cannot really be changed by the user since that is based on his motor. So he might be willing to change the PSI he requires. I'll have to talk to my boss and ask him, but I think maybe having the HP be kind of a limit, and then have the pump with the highest PSI at that available power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to calculate the [euclidian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)s between your pumps and the one defined by the user, then select the ones which are the closest.

Calculating the distance between two vectors is done by getting the square root of the sum of the squares of the differences of the vectors each nth elements.

```
A := (A[0], A[1], ..., A[n])
B := (B[0], B[1], ..., B[n])

distance = sqrt( (B[0]-A[0])^2 + (B[1]-A[1])^2 + ... + (B[n]-A[n])^2)
```

The same could be done with your Pumps, since they are technically property vectors.

```
double Dist(Pump a, Pump b)
{
    int PSIMinDiff = b.PSI_min - a.PSI_min;
    int PSIMaxDiff = b.PSI_max - a.PSI_max;
    int HorsepowerMinDiff = b.Horsepower_min - a.Horsepower_min;
    int RPMDiff = b.RPM - a.RPM;

    return Math.Sqrt(
        (PSIMinDiff * PSIMinDiff) +
        (PSIMaxDiff * PSIMaxDiff) +
        (HorsepowerMinDiff * HorsepowerMinDiff) +
        (RPMDiff * RPMDiff));
}
```

```
//Pump[] pumps   - all pumps
//Pump userPump  - the pump defined by the user

List<Pump> closestPumps = new List<Pump>();

//Get the lowest distance
double minDist = Double.MaxValue;
foreach(Pump p in pumps)
{
    double distance= Dist(p, userPump);
    if(distance < minDist) minDist = distance;
}

//Select pumps which are the closest to the one that the user defined
foreach(Pump p in pumps)
{
    if(Dist(p, userPump) == minDist)
        closestPumps.Add(p);
}
```

Note that while this method's easy to implement and use, one of it's biggest downsides is that it's not weighted, and while the results are mathematically correct, they may differ from the ones that the user wants to see.